# Junit TestRule annotates fields vs methods

Tags: junit4, junit-rule

Assuming you have a TestRule (for example, a TemporaryFolder) defined, you can apply the rule in a test class by either way below:

1.By annotating a method with @Rule

```
public MyTestClass{
  private TemporaryFolder folder= new TemporaryFolder();
  @Rule
  public TemporaryFolder getFolder() {
    return folder;
  }
  @Test
  ...
}
```

2.By annotating a field with @Rule

```
public MyTestClass{
  @Rule
  public TemporaryFolder folder= new TemporaryFolder();
  @Test
  ...
}
```

It seems that every test case invokes the *TemporaryFolder* constructor in both forms. What's the pros/cons of each form?

Answer (score 1):

The second version is more concise, otherwise they are identical. Allowing methods to be annotated by `Rule` was added for other JVM-based languages.